# Why do I have to place % at the end of line preceding \pstVerb?

Tags: pstricks, comments

Please consider the position of the red dots.

[image]

### First Case

When I don't activate `\pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}`, the red dot is properly positioned.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,griddots=0}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \pstGeonode{A}(1.5,0){B}(1.5,1.5){C}
    \pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{B}{C}
    %\pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}
    \psdots[linecolor=red](1,1)
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

### Second Case

When I activate `\pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}`, the red dot is displaced from its correct position.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,griddots=0}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \pstGeonode{A}(1.5,0){B}(1.5,1.5){C}
    \pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{B}{C}
    \pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}
    \psdots[linecolor=red](1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Third Case

When I append `%` at the end of `\pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{B}{C}`, the red dot returns to its proper position.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0,griddots=0}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \pstGeonode{A}(1.5,0){B}(1.5,1.5){C}
    \pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{B}{C}%<== why do I need this comment?
    \pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}
    \psdots[linecolor=red](1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### The question:

Why do I need to put `%` at the end of `\pstRightAngle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50]{A}{B}{C}` rather than at the end of `\pstVerb{/xxx 1 def}`? It is really confusing.

Comment: Note: Putting `%` at the end of `\pstVerb` (instead of `\pstRightAngle`) does not fix the displaced dot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a missing `\ignorespaces` at the end of `\pstRightAngle` in the code:

```
[...]
    \fi\fi\fi}%
  \egroup\ignorespaces%
}%
```

`\pstVerb` will also give a space but the following `\psdots` has a `\pst@killglue` at the beginning. So both, `\pstRightAngle` and `\pstVerb`, have a trailing space but only one is ignored by the following `\psdots`

Comment: So will you append `\ignorespaces` to both of them for the next build? Or there is a reason to  leave them as is?

Comment: not for `\pstVerb` which can also be used in the documents preamble.