# What makes my line get shifted to the left when I invoke \LoadConstants?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, fp

[image]

In the beginning I use the following code. So far so good.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
}


\const[1]{G}{9.8}
\const[1]{Tfinal}{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-G/2*#1^2}
\const[1]{Yfinal}{\y(Tfinal)}

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3.5,\Yfinal)
    \LoadConstants
    \psline(1.5,0)(1.5,\Yfinal)
    \multido{\n=0.0+0.5}{5}
    {
        \const[1]{Yt}{\y(\n)}%
        \rput[r](*1.25 {\y(\n)}){$\SI{\Yt}{\meter}$}
        \psline(1.4,\Yt)(1.6,\Yt)
        \rput[l](*1.75 {\y(\n)}){$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$}
        \pscircle*(*3.5 {\y(\n)}){5pt}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I changed my mind to use `Yt` instead of `\Yt` for the following. Because `Yt` is in PostScript world, I have to invoke an extra `\LoadConstants` again (see it in the looping).

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
}


\const[1]{G}{9.8}
\const[1]{Tfinal}{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-G/2*#1^2}
\const[1]{Yfinal}{\y(Tfinal)}

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3.5,\Yfinal)%
    \LoadConstants%
    \psline(1.5,0)(!1.5 Yfinal)%
    \multido{\n=0.0+0.5}{15}%
    {%
        \const[1]{Yt}{\y(\n)}%
        \LoadConstants%This is needed to provide Yt in PostScript world.
        \rput[r](*1.25 {\y(\n)}){$\SI{\Yt}{\meter}$}%
        \psline(!1.4 Yt)(!1.6 Yt)%
        \rput[l](*1.75 {\y(\n)}){$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$}%
        \pscircle*(*3.5 {\y(\n)}){5pt}%
    }%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the vertical line gets shifted to the left. I have tried to find the cause of problem but I give up. You can see I have removed all possible white spaces but the problem still exists.

Could  you find the source of problem? It is a hard puzzle!

### Edit:

I checked the value of `Yt`  using `\psPrintValue` and they use `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator. Is it OK?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
%\def\LoadConstants{}
%\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    %\edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    %\expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        %\expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        %\edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants\ignorespaces
            %\noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}\ignorespaces}\ignorespaces%
%}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}%
}

\const[1]{G}{9.8}
\const[1]{Tfinal}{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-G/2*#1^2}
\const[1]{Yfinal}{\y(Tfinal)}

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pst-tools}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](5,\Yfinal)%
    %\LoadConstants%
    \psline(1.5,0)(!1.5 Yfinal)%
    \multido{\n=0.0+0.5}{15}%
    {%
        \const[1]{Yt}{\y(\n)}%
        %\LoadConstants%
        \rput[r](*1.25 {\y(\n)}){$\SI{\Yt}{\meter}$}%
        \psline(!1.4 Yt)(!1.6 Yt)%
        \rput[l](*1.75 {\y(\n)}){$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$}%
        \pscircle*(*3.5 {\y(\n)}){5pt}%
        \rput(*4 {\y(\n)}){\psPrintValue{Yt}}
    }%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar to your other question [Why do I have to place `%` at the end of line preceding `\pstVerb`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102156/5764), there may be a missing `\ignorespaces` in the code that is revealed through this example...

Comment: @Karl'sstudents You can save a few keystrokes: `\SI{\Yt}{\meter}` --> `\SI{\Yt}{\m}` and `\SI{\n}{\second}` --> `\SI{\n}{\s}`.

Comment: @Herbert is right, adding `\pst@killglue` after the `\FPeval` statement solves the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an unprotected end of line in `fp-exp.sty`; add this to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\FP@pow#1#2#3{% <---- This was unprotected
  % #1 macro, which gets the result
  % #2 base
  % #3 exponent
  %
  \FP@beginmessage{POW}%
  %
  {\def\FP@beginmessage##1{}%
   \def\FP@endmessage##1{}%
   %
   \FPifzero{#2}%
     \FP@pow@zero{#3}%
   \else%
     \FPln\FP@tmpd{#2}%
     \FPmul\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd{#3}%
     \FPexp\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd%
   \fi%
   %
   \global\let\FP@tmp\FP@tmp%
  }%
  %
  \FP@endmessage{}%
  %
  \let#1\FP@tmp%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Here's the complete code for double checking. There are many `%` that I wouldn't use, but I left them nonetheless.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\def\LoadConstants{}
\newcommand\const[3][3]{%
    \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
        \edef\LoadConstants{\LoadConstants
            \noexpand\pstVerb{/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}%
}


\const[1]{G}{9.8}
\const[1]{Tfinal}{2.0}
\def\y(#1){-G/2*#1^2}
\const[1]{Yfinal}{\y(Tfinal)}

\SpecialCoor
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
\def\FP@pow#1#2#3{%
  % #1 macro, which gets the result
  % #2 base
  % #3 exponent
  %
  \FP@beginmessage{POW}%
  %
  {\def\FP@beginmessage##1{}%
   \def\FP@endmessage##1{}%
   %
   \FPifzero{#2}%
     \FP@pow@zero{#3}%
   \else%
     \FPln\FP@tmpd{#2}%
     \FPmul\FP@tmpd\FP@tmpd{#3}%
     \FPexp\FP@tmp\FP@tmpd%
   \fi%
   %
   \global\let\FP@tmp\FP@tmp%
  }%
  %
  \FP@endmessage{}%
  %
  \let#1\FP@tmp%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3.5,\Yfinal)%
    \LoadConstants%
    \psline(1.5,0)(!1.5 Yfinal)%
    \multido{\n=0.0+0.5}{15}%
    {%
        \const[1]{Yt}{\y(\n)}%
        \LoadConstants%This is needed to provide Yt in PostScript world.
        \rput[r](*1.25 {\y(\n)}){$\SI{\Yt}{\meter}$}%
        \psline(!1.4 Yt)(!1.6 Yt)%
        \rput[l](*1.75 {\y(\n)}){$t=\SI{\n}{\second}$}%
        \pscircle*(*3.5 {\y(\n)}){5pt}%
    }%
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

The unprotected end-of-line is on line 444 of `fp-exp.sty`.

Comment: Do I have to do this in every project? Or will it be fixed for the next release of `fp-pow.sty`?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents As far as I can tell, `fp` hasn't been touched since 1995, so I can't foresee a "next release". You probably have better to edit the original file or make an amended copy of it in the local tree. However, you can raise the question in the [TeX Live list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) and probably the maintainers will amend the file themselves (it's just a typo).

Comment: There is no `fp-pow` but `fp-exp`. Thank you. The bounty will be offered until the bounty button is available.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents Yes, it's `fp-exp`; I was confused with the name of the macro.

Comment: The package `fp` has been updated in January 2019 and the patch is no longer needed.