# Rounding a number to its hundred

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, calculations

Does anybody know how I could have LaTeX round a number like `2,386` so that I finally get only written `2,300`?

I tried with `siunitx` and its option `[round-mode=places,round-precision=-2]` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you wanted to round to `2400` this would be easy: round figures rather than places. However, you seem to want to round _down_: is that correct?

Comment: Can you tell whether the comma is the decimal or a thousands separator?

Comment: @egreg I think the precision in the question implies the `,` is a thousand separator, but that doesn't help with the rounding down!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `siunitx` and `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hundreds}{O{}m}
 {
  \num[#1]{\fp_eval:n { trunc(#2,-2) }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hundreds{2348}

\hundreds[group-four-digits,group-separator={,}]{2348}

\sisetup{group-four-digits,group-separator={,}}

\hundreds{2348}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about `trunc` but hadn't tried negative positions :-) Did you consider simply using a version of `\fp_eval:n` in the arg of `\num` but avoiding an entirely separate command?

Comment: @JosephWright The main problem is how to normalize the input: if one uses `\hundreds{2,348}`, the result will be wrong. But, IIRC, all such functions in `siunitx` are private.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a **LuaLaTeX**-based solution to the problem of *truncating* a number to the closest multiple of 100. Positive and negative numbers are both truncated *toward* zero.

The `\ensuremath` macro, provided by the `amsmath` package, is used to make it unnecessary to keep track of whether the `\mytrunc` macro is used inside or outside of one of TeX's math mode environments.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "\ensuremath" macro
% Create a TeX macro that invokes the lua library function 'math.fmod'
\newcommand\mytrunc[1]{%
   \ensuremath{ \directlua{ tex.sprint( #1 - math.fmod(#1,100) ) }}}

\begin{document}
2386 $\to$ \mytrunc{2386}

$-149$ $\to$ \mytrunc{-149}

$-186$ $\to$ \mytrunc{-186}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wha don't you use simply `$\directlua{ tex.sprint(#1 - math.fmod(#1,100)) }$` ?

Comment: @Herbert - excellent suggestion. :-)  I'll change the code.

Answer (score 5):

Divide it by 100 then multiply the result by 100.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\mycount
\mycount = 2386
\divide\mycount by 100
\multiply\mycount by 100
\begin{document}
\number\mycount
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution requires the number to be integer-valued, right? You may want to mention this fact explicitly, for the benefit of those readers who don't know much about TeX's `count` registers...

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun with `fp`.

### Rounding

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}


\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\rounder[2]{\FPeval\x{round(round(#1*pow(-#2,10):0)*pow(#2,10):0)}\x}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\foreach \i in {2440,2441,..., 2460}{\item \i\ is rounded to \rounder{\i}{2}.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Truncating

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}


\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\rounder[2]{\FPeval\x{round(trunc(#1*pow(-#2,10):0)*pow(#2,10):0)}\x}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\foreach \i in {2440,2441,..., 2450}{\item \i\ is truncated to \rounder{\i}{2}.}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Bonus

Can you spot an oddity?

Comment: I don't why there are extra white spaces between `to` and the number. Confusing...

Comment: Use an `\unskip` to get rid of it and afterwards force a regular space.

Comment: Probably the usual unprotected end-of-line in `fp`. Oh, and it's odd that 2450 is rounded to 2400 instead of 2500.

Comment: @egreg I wouldn't say that it's odd at all that 2450 is rounded to 2400. Even based rounding is a very popular rounding technique for addressing the conundrum that is the halfway point between two numbers (0.5). I mainly know this technique as banker's rounding but it goes by a lot of names. 2050 --> 2000. 2150 --> 2200. 2250 --> 2200. 2350 --> 2400. Even based rounding tends to produce simpler math later than the parallel odd based rounding.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - But does this code produce "banker's rouding"?

Comment: @Mico I'm thinking yes since I just found the following comment near the top of the l3fp-round.dtx file in the LaTeX repository ([link](http://latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/l3kernel/l3fp-round.dtx)): "The \enquote{round to nearest} mode is the default.  If the \meta{digit_2} is larger than~$5$, then round up.  If it is less than~$5$, round down.  If it is exactly $5$, then round such that \meta{digit_1} plus the result is even.  In other words, round up if \meta{digit_1} is odd."

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - Hmmm, when I run "cyanide-based food"'s code, I get `\rounder{2150}{2}` = 2100 instead of 2200. Similarly, `\rounder{2350}` = 2300 instead of 2400. Am I missing something about the essence of "banker's rounding"? Or does `l3fp`'s actual rounding algorithm maybe not cohere with its stated method?

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood The unprotected end-of-line is at line 444 of `fp-exp.sty`. The one we already knew about ([What makes my line get shifted to the left when I invoke \LoadConstants?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107571/))

Comment: @Mico Hmmm that is interesting. Do you get `\rounder(2450)` = 2400 as cyanide did above?? My curiosity will force me to dig deeper into the methodology when I have time. Maybe I can find time tonight. What you are showing makes it seem like a round toward zero for midpoint round which introduces an identical magnitude of rounding error to the presumption that 0.5 should round up. Not any worse.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - Indeed, the result of `\rounder{2450}{2}` is 2400, as is also shown in the original answer.

Comment: @Mico Seems perhaps that it doesn't line up with that code comment. All of your examples seem to match a round to zero approach to ties. This rounding is probably less common than round away from zero but does get used and has the same magnitude of bias as the latter. Based on my reading of the comments, round away from zero is what egreg and cyanide expected.

Comment: For the record, contrary to the comments above, this has nothing to do with `l3fp`.  `fp` is a different (older) package.

Comment: Thanks. Solution helped where I had conflicts with siunitx. Works fine with numprint pacage to get currencies rounded: `\newcommand\rounder[2][2]{\FPeval\x{round(round(#2*pow(-#1,10):0)*pow(#1,10):0)}\numprint{\x}}
`

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\twodec#1{\expandafter\twodecB#1,,,\@nil}
\def\twodecB#1,#2#3#4\@nil{\ifx,#2 #1,000\else#1,#200\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\twodec{2}\par
\twodec{2,3}\par
\twodec{2,38}\par
\twodec{2,386}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For R users, an easy option is  a `file.Rnw` file like that:

```
<<echo=F>>=
a <- 100
rounddown <- function(x){format(floor(x/a)*a,   big.mark = ",")} 
@

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 Rounded down 2,326 is \Sexpr{rounddown(2326)}.
\end{document}
```

That with `R CMD Sweave file.Rnw` is converted to a true `file.tex` like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
Rounded down 2,326 is 2,300.
\end{document}
```