# How to round numbers to hundreds, i.e., to the nearest multiple of 100

Tags: siunitx, calculations

I want to round numbers to hundreds. I note [Rounding a number to its hundred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197844/rounding-a-number-to-its-hundred). However, the question asks about rounding `2,386.0` *down* to `2,300.0` -- and I would want it to be rounded up to `2,400.0`, and I would want `2,326.0` to be rounded down to `2,300.0`.

How to do this?

According to a comment by joseph-wright, it would be easy, but after reading and trying for an hour, I decided to ask here.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hundreds}{O{}m}
 {
  \num[#1]{\fp_eval:n { trunc(#2,-2) }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\myhundreds}[1]{\num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=-2]{#1}}
\begin{document}

\hundreds{2348}

\hundreds[group-four-digits,group-separator={,}]{2348}

\sisetup{group-four-digits,group-separator={,}}

\hundreds{2399}

\hundreds{2301}

\myhundreds{2300}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `round` rather than `trunc`. From the `l3fp` documentation:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hundreds}{O{}m}
 {
  \num[#1]{\fp_eval:n { round(#2,-2) }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hundreds{2348}

\hundreds[group-four-digits,group-separator={,}]{2348}

\sisetup{group-four-digits,group-separator={,}}

\hundreds{2399}

\hundreds{2301}

\end{document}
```

This prints `2300 2,300 2,400 2,300`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the sake of variety, here's LuaLaTeX-based solution. It provides a LaTeX macro called `\hundreds`. The input of this macro must be either a number or an expression that evaluates to a number according to Lua's syntax rules; its output is that number rounded to the nearest multiple of 100. The LaTeX macro `\hundreds` uses LuaTeX's `tex.sprint` function as well as a utility Lua function called `math.round_int` which rounds a number to the nearest integer.

The `\hundreds` macro can be placed in the argument of `\num` for further pretty-printing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-four-digits,group-separator={,}]{siunitx} % for \num macro   
% define a Lua function called 'math.round_int':
\directlua{%
function math.round_int ( x )
   return x>=0 and math.floor(x+0.5) or math.ceil(x-0.5)
end
}
\newcommand{\hundreds}[1]{\directlua{%
   tex.sprint(100*math.floor(math.round_int((#1)/100)))}}

\begin{document}
\hundreds{2348};
\hundreds{2399};
\hundreds{2301};
\hundreds{23*100+10}; % arg evaluates to '2310'
\num{\hundreds{2301}}
\end{document}
```